# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named "my PU Name"

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I searched all options but nothing at now worked for me.
I'm with this issue creating the tables of my database

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named FinanceiroPU
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>       at com.ronaldosistemas.financeiro.factory.CriaTabelas.main(CriaTabelas.java:9)

this is my CriaTabelas.Java

```
package com.ronaldosistemas.financeiro.factory;

import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class CriaTabelas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("FinanceiroPU");

    }
}
```

this is my persistense.xml and its location

```
<persistence-unit name="FinanceiroPU">
    <!-- Implementação do JPA, no nosso caso Hibernate -->
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/financeiro" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

[persistence location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEbYJ.png)

and finally this is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ronaldosistemas</groupId>
<artifactId>financeiro</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <!-- OmniFaces (utilitarios para JSF) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- PrimeFaces (biblioteca de componentes) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Weld (implementação do CDI) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Weld depende do Jandex -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Implementacao do Bean Validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Núcleo do Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Implementação de EntityManager da JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Driver JDBC do MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Mojarra (implementacao do JSF) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

i swith the provider and updated my sql connector and hibernate persistence jar but still not working

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

please someone could help me ? many thanks

Comment: Sure you have the right jars added? Setting a breakpoint in the class that throws the exception might help. I had this once and the right jars were not in the runtime deployment

Answer (score 0):

my issue has been solved after trade persistense.xml head.
i think i'm using a old version

below the correct

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
```